# How to get individual count of same value rows with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just want to know how to get individual count of same value rows with join using mysql and help are definitely appreciated

Here is my mysql Query

```
SELECT c.`id` 
  FROM categories c inner join subcategories sc 
           on c.`id` = sc.`cat_id`
```

See the Response screeshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT c.`id`, count(1)
  FROM categories c inner join subcategories sc 
       on c.`id` = sc.`cat_id`
 GROUP BY c.`id`
```

Comment: Thank for sharing me your experience

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a basic task. Consider studying GROUP BY and aggregate functions.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) 
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN subcategories sn ON c.id = sn.cat_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: I hate the fact that MySQL doesn't force you to do a `group by` with grouped aggregate functions. :-)

Comment: @Pablo What? I don't understand.

Comment: your initial query didn't have a `group by` clause. MySQL does not force you to have that clause. All other RDBMS I know, do.

Comment: Ah, ok, I accidentally send answer before completing. Anyway, if forced, how can you use aggregates on full table, eg for row counting or grand totals?

Comment: in that case, they don't force you. but the minute you put a non-aggregated column in the `select clause`, you are forced to include it in the `group by` clause. With MySQL, you don't have this restriction. I don't know why.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz Uh, right, if there are no other selected column, a global grouping is allowed. Learned something new today :) Thank you.